# Boost Unit testing- where to locate makefiles

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, build, compilation

I would like to use Boost for unit testing. Writing the unit tests is not a problem. However, I am a little unsure how to structure the makefiles relating to each unit test. I am not an expert on makefiles so I would like to explain how my code base is, what I would like to do and then ask for the best solution.

I have a code base which is a mixture of Python, C++ utility functions in headers and one C++ application/library, but it uses the classes/functions located in other folders (which are not sub folders). So unsurprisingly I only have one makefile for my application.

I would like to add unit tests in each of the various folders my application uses.

I would also like to be able to run all the unit tests (across the multiple folders) by running one executable.

Do I write a boost unit test source file in each folder and add a corresponding makefile, one per each folder I wish to unit test? How do I structure this so that I can run all the unit tests from one executable?

Also, do I need to link my unit test makefiles to my application object file, or just gcc -I flag the headers it requires?

(I am using regular GNU Make)

Comment: This question gives me a dejavu. Anyway, to run all the unit tests as the single executable you will need to compile and link all the translation units containing those tests into a single executable along with required libraries, if any. There are multiple ways to do this with many / single / without make files, but none of them could really be considered a preferred.

Comment: @VTT Could you give me something I can google, to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: Since you already have an application and a make file I assume that you are aware of how to build executables with make. Building unit test executable wouldn't be much of a difference. It would be difficult to give universal suggestions on how to exactly structure your make file(s) since many approaches are possible.

Comment: @VTT I'm not hugely experienced with Make. Do I just need one "boost unit test"  makefile, which says to begin at the root of my directory and find all boost unit test source files and compile them?